# How is “days destroyed” different from “amount of BTC” in existence?

Tags: transactions

According to https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Days_Destroyed , if I have 100 BTC for seven days and then spend them, that’s 700 days destroyed.

But if I didn't have them, someone else would have them.  So how does the metric differ from the amount of BTC that exists?

Answer (score 0):

Days destroyed are measured in BTC * days
Amounts of BTC are measured in BTCs

The two concepts are as different as Power (Watts) vs Energy (Joules).

Comment: Understood.  But one is linearly proportional to the other.  So why do we need both?  With power and energy, we’re usually dealing with a subset of the set of devices or of the supply, so the difference is meaningful.  No doubt there’s some other detail I’m missing.

Comment: Not true. The UPPER BOUND of Days-destroyed is linearly proportional to the total amount of BTC in existence. But if no transactions occur, then Days-destroyed will not grow.

Comment: “no transactions occurring” is a hypothetical that will never happen.  So days destroyed correlates to the amount not being spent?  Wait, that still sounds like what I said before.  I guess I still don’t get it.